# select count(*) does not give correct count

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to count total sum of all the three following results, but i am getting count of one result only.

```
$sql = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  table1 WHERE somecondition)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  table2 WHERE somecondition)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  table3 WHERE somecondition)";
```

Can anyone help.thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query will return three rows, with the three separate counts.

What you want is

```
  select sum(c) from (
      (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM  table1 WHERE somecondition)
      UNION
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  table2 WHERE somecondition)
      UNION
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  table3 WHERE somecondition)
  ) all_three
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this....

```
SELECT sum(
 ( SELECT count(*) from table1)
+ ( SELECT count(*) from table2)
+ ( SELECT count(*) from table3)
+ ( SELECT count(*) from table4) )as total from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for count of every table as different field the..

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM table_1) As first_count,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM table_2) As second_count,   
        (SELECT count(*) FROM table_3) As third_count
```

And if want to sum of all count of all 3 tables then

```
SELECT SUM ((SELECT count(*) FROM table_1) +
       (SELECT count(*) FROM table_2) +
        (SELECT count(*) FROM table_3) ) AS total_count
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query will return 3 rows- each for table.

Use this query instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(C) FROM(
(SELECT COUNT(*) as C FROM  table1 WHERE somecondition)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) as C FROM  table2 WHERE somecondition)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) as C FROM  table3 WHERE somecondition)
)";
```

(You need to tune your query depending upon the database you are using)

Comment: i am using mysql and i am a novice, learning mysql/php. I tried above but is still not working, am i missing something?